# "Top questions" in careers.stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, jobs

How about adding an optional "top questions" section to my careers page?

I would argue that being able to clearly and effectively communicate a problem you're having, by writing a good question, may be just as important to employers as being able to provide good answers.